# How do I serve the same language regardless of the selected one in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

My client had me set up a language picker on his Wordpress website to let visitors choose where they come from (UK, US, France, Switzerland). Now he wants the content to be served in French no matter what language the visitor picks, with a content slightly different.

Example : if the visitor picks UK, then the page has to be in French with UK specific content (like some different texts).

I've set up WPML and added the countries to the language picker.
I've then duplicated the pages to have the same content no matter what language is picked, and that seems to work ok. The problem is, that built-in stuff like log-in buttons, account, etc are displayed in the selected language.

How should I proceed ?
I thought of "breaking" the existing translations and manually replace localized built in translations by the French equivalent, but that sounds like a tedious task.

Comment: I'm nt sure if WPML is prepared for this kind of misusage, but maybe you can add FR multiple times and just give it other language slugs?

Comment: I've tried to, there's an "href" column in the language table but WPML won't let me set the same href for multiple languages, I just realized I could try to force the value in the db